# Downgrading from iOS 6.0.1 to iOS 5.1.1?

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to downgrade from iOS 6 to iOS 5.1.1?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64559/how-to-downgrade-from-ios-6-to-ios-5-1-1)

So i have an iPod Touch 4th Generation that is iOS 6.0.1 and i recently bought an Apple Peel 520 2nd Generation. I could be wrong but im pretty sure that the Apple Peel 520 2nd Generation doesn't support iOS 6.0.1 and if it doesn't which Apple Peel Device (or something similar) does? I looked up some stuff and so far what i found out is that the Apple Peel 520 2nd Generation supports iOS 5.1.1 but here's the catch. I bought my iPod Touch 4th Generation a few months ago at Walmart and it already had iOS 6.0 and a day or two later iOS 6.0.1 came out and i downloaded that. But that was BEFORE i found out about the Apple Peel 520 2nd Generation. So does that mean that i can't downgrade? And if i definately cannot downgrade, does anyone know of any other Apple Peel Device (or something similar) by Yosion or other similar companies that will?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot downgrade your device. It is forever locked to iOS 6.0.1.

A downgrade for certain devices (those that run on the A4 processor, and yours does) is only possible should you have the SHSH blobs (using Redsnow). However, since you do not have them, there is no way to revert to any version prior to 6.0.1 (unless you saved the blobs for 6.0, then you could certainly revert to the prior version).